# What are the options of bluetooth-agent?

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian, bluez

I found no answer to this simple question: What are the options that `bluetooth-agent` accepts? I am using raspbian, based on debian wheezy, which uses bluez v 4.99

- the website of bluez has *no* information whatsoever
- the help message is scarce and does not cover all the options!

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the source code for `bluez 4.99`, file `test/agent.c`

- `--adapter X` or `-a X` : specify the path to the adapter
- `--path X` or `-p X` : specify agent path (what is this??) defaults to `/org/bluez/agent_XXX` where `XXX` is the pid
- `--capabilities X` or `-c X` : defaults to `DisplayYesNo`
- `--delay X` or `-d X` : X should be an integer, used as a delay for connection (?), defaults to 0.
- `--reject` or `-r` : reject connections
- `--help` or `-h` : "help" message